# Cart lifecycle with cookie

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, shopping-cart

I have an implementation Of the cart that is using Session and want to migrate to a cookie based one. Moreover actually I am storing the complete cart in the session and want to migrate to a version where only the cartID is in the cookie while the content is in a database.

I have read many blog posts and even questions on SO but still have some confusion on some area:

- how is the cookie lyfecycle? Actually I create a new cart when a new session begins. Then I manage the session based on customer action (add to cart, remove from cart, clear on checkout)
- how can I create a unique cookieId
- which is the best way to handle the backing to database task? Using jQuery or it is better to handle everything server side?

For instance I am using asp net mvc with c#.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've used Session to save entire shopping cart. Later, I stored just Shopping Cart ID in cookie, and actual items in database.

In my scenario, I temporarily store items in Shopping Cart first. After checkout is successful, I move items from Shopping Cart to ***Order*** and ***OrderItem*** tables, and delete the Cart.

Here is what you can learn from my mistake.

> how is the cookie lifecycle? Actually,I create a new cart when a new
>   session begins. Then I manage the session based on customer action
>   (add to cart, remove from cart, clear on checkout)

Do not create cookie when a new session begins. Instead, you want to create an entry in database, only after a customer adds an item to a cart. Then store that ***GUID*** in cookie.

The main reason is if you create cookie too early, you will end up with too many abandoned cart.

***FYI:*** you want to schedule a task to clear up abandoned carts after certain time frame.

> how can I create a unique cookieId

Make database column ID ***uniqueidentifier***. After a new shopping cart is created, then save the returned GUID in cookie.

> which is the best way to handle the backing to database task? Using
>   jQuery or it is better to handle everything server side?

You want to generate GUID from server-side as above.

***Do not use Integer with Identity Increment. It'll end up with big security hole, because you can predict the number easily.***

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience. Ho do you handle anonymous carts? That is carts for users who does'nt have logged in yet?

Comment: I create ***UserId*** column *(allow null)* next to ***GUID*** primary key column. If anonymous user add an item to cart, I leave ***UserId*** blank. After they login, I go back and populate the ***UserId*** with user's Id.

Comment: @win thank you for this very valuable answer containing great insight.  Very helpful for someone designing a shopping cart for the first time.